# Xcache - No different after using it

Tags: php, xcache, lighttpd

Hi
I have installed Xcache in my site(using xampp), I have tested more then 10 times on several page and the result is same as default(no any cache installed), is it something wrong with the configure?

Updated

```
[xcache-common]
;; install as zend extension (recommended), normally "$extension_dir/xcache.so"
zend_extension = /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/non-debug-non-zts-xxx/xcache.so
 zend_extension_ts = /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/non-debug-zts-xxx/xcache.so
;; For windows users, replace xcache.so with php_xcache.dll
zend_extension_ts = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xcache.dll
;; or install as extension, make sure your extension_dir setting is correct
; extension = xcache.so
;; or win32:
; extension = php_xcache.dll

[xcache.admin]
xcache.admin.enable_auth = On
xcache.admin.user = "mOo"
; xcache.admin.pass = md5($your_password)
xcache.admin.pass = ""

[xcache]
; ini only settings, all the values here is default unless explained

; select low level shm/allocator scheme implemenation
xcache.shm_scheme =        "mmap"
; to disable: xcache.size=0
; to enable : xcache.size=64M etc (any size > 0) and your system mmap allows
xcache.size  =               60M
; set to cpu count (cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep -c processor)
xcache.count =                 1
; just a hash hints, you can always store count(items) > slots
xcache.slots =                8K
; ttl of the cache item, 0=forever
xcache.ttl   =                 0
; interval of gc scanning expired items, 0=no scan, other values is in seconds
xcache.gc_interval =           0

; same as aboves but for variable cache
xcache.var_size  =            4M
xcache.var_count =             1
xcache.var_slots =            8K
; default ttl
xcache.var_ttl   =             0
xcache.var_maxttl   =          0
xcache.var_gc_interval =     300

xcache.test =                Off
; N/A for /dev/zero
xcache.readonly_protection = Off
; for *nix, xcache.mmap_path is a file path, not directory.
; Use something like "/tmp/xcache" if you want to turn on ReadonlyProtection
; 2 group of php won't share the same /tmp/xcache
; for win32, xcache.mmap_path=anonymous map name, not file path
xcache.mmap_path =    "/dev/zero"


; leave it blank(disabled) or "/tmp/phpcore/"
; make sure it's writable by php (without checking open_basedir)
xcache.coredump_directory =   ""

; per request settings
xcache.cacher =               On
xcache.stat   =               On
xcache.optimizer =           Off

[xcache.coverager]
; per request settings
; enable coverage data collecting for xcache.coveragedump_directory and xcache_coverager_start/stop/get/clean() functions (will hurt executing performance)
xcache.coverager =          Off

; ini only settings
; make sure it's readable (care open_basedir) by coverage viewer script
; requires xcache.coverager=On
xcache.coveragedump_directory = ""
```

Thanks you

Comment: @Charles Yeung - where is your configuration?

Comment: Please see updated for the configuration

Comment: are you configuring this for a windows or for a *nix platform?

Comment: Sorry, don't know what is "nix platform", but I am using Windows XP + xampp 1.7.1

Comment: *nix is Unix or Linux, an alternative operating system to Windows. You've uncommented lines like zend_extension = /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/non-debug-non-zts-xxx/xcache.so which is enabling it for *nix as well as zend_extension_ts = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xcache.dll which enables it for Windows. Try recommenting the .so reference lines

Comment: Post your phpinfo() output so that we can be sure you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

To see what could be achieved, as a sample, you could get the entire output of that pages computation, store it as a serialized variable with xcache..

Then run the page once loading all the computational data from the cache.. and once rebuilding all the data from scratch.

In my experience, you can see anything from a 2x - 10x performance increase depending on your pages 'intensity'.